# partial specialization for iterator type of a specified container type

Tags: c++, templates, partial-specialization

I have a template struct, which accepts a Iterator type for the template argument.
now I need to specialize that class for iterators of different containers. 
I have tried with std::vector

```
template<typename Iterator>
struct AC {

};

template<typename T, typename Alloc>
struct AC<typename std::vector<T, Alloc>::iterator> { //this doesn't work

};
```

but I got this compiler error(VS11):
'T' : template parameter not used or deducible in partial specialization

Can someone please tell me why this doesn't work? And how to make it work?

Comment: Why do you want to specialize for iterators of different containers? Specializing a vector<T> iterator will probably not be use as it might just be T*. Are you trying to see if in iterator supports random access, in that case you want iterator_traits::iterator_category

Comment: @JohnBandela : I want to expend the iterator category, write my own iterator_traits, and make it compatible with stl containers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't deduce types left of a nesting `::`. Indeed, your question makes no sense. Consider this simpler counter-example:

```
template <typename> struct Foo;
template <> struct Foo<bool> { typedef float type; };
template <> struct Foo<char> { typedef float type; };

template <typename> struct DoesntWork;

template <typename T> struct DoesntWork<typename Foo<T>::type> { };
```

Now if I say `DoesntWork<float>`, what should `T` be?

The point is that there is no reason that *any* `T` should exist for which `Foo<T>::type` is a thing you want to match, and even if there were one, there's no reason why it would be unique.