# How to specialize template on arbitrary dependent type

Tags: c++, templates, specialization

Say, I have some template which specialized for several types, `TypeMathcer`, which has `type` member.

```
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
struct TypeMatcher;

template <typename T>
struct TypeMatcher<T *>
{
    // making some type from T
    typedef std::shared_ptr<T> type;
};

template <typename T>
struct TypeMatcher<T&>
{
    // making other type from T
    typedef std::vector<T> type;
};
```

Now, I want to create another template and specialize it for types I get from `TypeMatcher`. If I do it straightforward, like this

```
template <typename T>
struct MyNeedfullTemplate;

template <typename T>
struct MyNeedfullTemplate<typename TypeMatcher<T>::type>
{    
};
```

I get compiler error: `template parameters not deducible in partial specialization`.

Same error if use `using` syntax

```
template <typename T>
using type_matcher_t = typename TypeMatcher<T>::type;

template <typename T>
struct MyNeedfullTemplate;

template <typename T>
struct MyNeedfullTemplate<type_matcher_t<T> >
{
};
```

I read answer to question [partial specialization for iterator type of a specified container type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16123279/partial-specialization-for-iterator-type-of-a-specified-container-type) that is very similar to my question, but still not sure if existing of one counter-example makes all question senseless. Also now we have brand-new c++14 and c++17 standards which could change situation. So what if I ensure the specializations is unique and exists, will than any possibility to make parameters deducible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is impossible, on principle, and no fancy C++9999 can change that.

What you're asking the compiler to do:

There's a use such as `MyNeedfulTemplate<int>` in the code. The compiler needs a definition of `MyNeedfulTemplate<U>` for `U = int`. You've tried to provide a partial specialisation of the form

```
template <typename T>
struct MyNeedfullTemplate<typename TypeMatcher<T>::type>
```

To see whether this specialisation applies or not, the compiler would have to inspect `TypeMatcher<T>` for **all possible `T`s** and find if any one of them has a nested typedef `type` that aliases `int`. This cannot happen, as the set of "all possible `T`s" is infinite. OK, `TypeMatcher<int>` doesn't have such a type, and neither does `TypeMatcher<int*>`, nor `TypeMatcher<int**>`, nor `TypeMatcher<int***>`. But what if `TypeMatcher<int****>` does? Better keep trying...

Also remember that partial and complete specialisation exists, meaning that `TypeMatcher` itself could be specialised.

In short, there is *no* way to link an `int` to a `TypeMatcher<X>::type` if all you have is the `int` and not the `X`.

---

You should be able to achieve something similar by re-structuring (inverting) `TypeMatcher` a bit:

```
template <class T>
struct TypeMatcher2
{
  static constexpr specialised = false;
};

template <class T>
struct TypeMatcher2<std::shared_ptr<T>>
{
  static constexpr specialised = true;
  using OldType = T*;
};

template <class T>
struct TypeMatcher2<std::vector<T>>
{
  static constexpr specialised = true;
  using OldType = T&;
}

template <class T, bool spec = TypeMatcher2<T>::specialised>
struct MyNeedfullTemplate
{
  // generic version
};

template <class T>
struct MyNeedfullTemplate<T, true>
{
  using OriginalT = typename TypeMatcher2<T>::OldType;

  // specialised version
};
```

Comment: OK, I see. But is there any common pattern to replace this kind of template? Something like traits or maybe other thing I don't know.

Comment: @user2807083 I've added a potential solution (assuming I understand your use-case correctly).

Comment: Oh, that is. I suspected that there is some solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you're trying to do is this:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <memory>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

template <typename T>
struct TypeMatcher;

template <typename T>
struct TypeMatcher<T *>
{
    // making some type from T
    typedef std::shared_ptr<T> type;
};

template <typename T>
struct TypeMatcher<T&>
{
    // making other type from T
    typedef std::vector<T> type;
};


template <typename T, typename = void>
struct MyNeedfullTemplate;

template <typename T>
struct MyNeedfullTemplate<TypeMatcher<T>, std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<typename TypeMatcher<T>::type, std::vector<std::remove_reference_t<T>>>::value>>
{
    static void report() { std::cout << "hello" << std::endl; }
};
int main()
{
    using matcher_type = TypeMatcher<int&>;
    using full_type = MyNeedfullTemplate<matcher_type>;
    full_type::report();

    return 0;
}
```

Do I understand the question correctly?

Comment: Nearly, but I don't mean to write separated specialization for each type, matched by `TypeMatcher`, because threre is infinite set of such types.

Comment: I would need to understand how the type of a TypeMatcher was decided upon before commenting further I think

Comment: I oversimplified example I think. The base problem I had was with variadic template and type lists, from which I try to extract odd and even types as separate type lists and than apply `std::is_convertible` for each type pair. It need to think more about this and maybe someday I could ask right question. Still can't formulate exatly what I need.

Comment: I see. So this class is a meta-predicate in reality? Well hopefully this answer offers a step in the right direction